# Perforce stream view import path strips file extension

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I have 2 streams right now, and in my second stream I want to import certain files from the other stream based on their file extensions.

If I set it up using the following statements:

```
import from_second_stream/... //second_stream/....xml
import from_second_stream/... //second_stream/....json
```

It successfully imports all the files in the correct place, but it strips the file extensions.
For instance, I have a file in the second stream in this path:

```
//second_stream/test/myTest.json
```

Which should get imported as:

```
from_second_stream/test/myTest.json
```

But instead becomes:

```
from_second_stream/test/myTest
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried placing ".xml" and ".json" at the end of the left sides of the mappings? (So the first line would read "import from_second_stream/....xml //second_stream/....xml")

Comment: Yeah I did, but it wasn't accepted by perforce. Take a look at the answer for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Perforce support:

> The path should be:
>
> import from_second_stream/....json //second_stream/....json
>
> However it is not allowed to have embedded wildcards in stream views, so you will not be able to use that. Instead you need to specify each file in the view:
>
> import from_second_stream/test/myTest.json //second_stream/test/myTest.json

So we ended up having to restructure our build system to accommodate this...